# How to hide Cash payment option on onclick of Store Credit payment option?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

How to hide Cash payment option on onclick of Store Credit payment option?

[image]

Comment: Which class do you extend with your custom method?

Comment: could u please share screenshot